# How to show scrollbars for the canvas wpf

Tags: wpf, canvas, drag-and-drop, onmousemove

I implemented the canvas from the code project example [Drag controls in canvas](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas?msg=5411352#xx5411352xx)

Here user has the ability to move anywhere in the canvas, when control reaches top or bottom, i want to show the vertical scrollbar. How can I make this work?

Comment: See this topic: [Scrollviewer & Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504869/scrollviewer-canvas).

Comment: That didn't worked, scrollbars are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid  Name="grid">      
        <Canvas Name="canvastoExport" >           
            <Polygon Points="200,100,300,100,300,200,200,200" Fill="Green"></Polygon>            
        </Canvas>      
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: you will need to put the canvas in a grid and the grid in a scrollviewer